# How to generate an svg image from multiple small svg components?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have the below `svg` component. I want to stack multiple same `svg` components horizontally and vertically, to generate a bigger `svg` image in a grid.

I can stack them together but how do I convert it to an `svg`?
Please suggest, and if there is any package I can use. Thanks.

**SVG Component**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function MySVG() {
  return (
    <svg version="1.1" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
      <defs/>
      <g/>
      <g transform="scale(1,1)">
          <g transform="scale(1,1)">
              <rect id="cell" fill="rgb(16,28,138)" stroke="none" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" fill-opacity="0.40784313725490196"/>
          </g>
          <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(163,127,18)" paint-order="fill stroke markers" d=" M 0 0 L 0 40" stroke-opacity="0.7294117647058823" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
          <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(163,127,18)" paint-order="fill stroke markers" d=" M 40 0 L 40 40" stroke-opacity="0.7294117647058823" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
          <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(163,127,18)" paint-order="fill stroke markers" d=" M 0 0 L 40 0" stroke-opacity="0.7294117647058823" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
          <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(163,127,18)" paint-order="fill stroke markers" d=" M 0 40 L 40 40" stroke-opacity="0.7294117647058823" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

**App Component**

```
import React from "react";
import MySVG from "./MySVG";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return [...Array(5).keys()].map((i) => <MySVG key={i} />);
}
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-liskov-ps1kx?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Use the svg as a pattern.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you v much!!